# ForAll the current Gallery Items and update the related SharePoint items based on the value inside the gallery

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have this gallery >> when the user click on the + icon >> i will add a new empty record inside the SharePoint list >> then the user will enter the related info >> click on submit to update the gallery items:.

Here is the gallery:-

[image]

and here is the formula to ForAll the GalleryItems and update the SharePoint item:-

```
ForAll(PrintOrderDetailsGallery.AllItems,
Patch('Printing Orders Details',ThisRecord,{Quantity:PrintOrderQuantity,'Quantity Each Artwork':PrintOrderQuantityForEachartwork.Text,'Network ID':PrintOrderNetworkComboBox.Selected.ID}));
```

but currently the ForAll will not update the sharepoint list? any advice?

Answer (score 1):

## Fix:

If you want to update items already saved on SharePoint (but with no value, only auto generated ID), you can use a `LookUp` on the SharePoint datasource and filter on ID, instead of using `ThisRecord`. Something like that:

```
   Patch('Printing Orders Details',
         LookUp('Printing Orders Details', ID = 100),
         {
            'Quantity': 123,
            'Quantity Each Artwork': 456,
            'Network ID': 789
          }
    )
```

## Improvement:

Using a Patch in a ForAll could be slow. There is a technique to Patch a collection, without a ForAll. You can check this great article of Matthew Devaney: [PATCH Multiple Records In Power Apps 10x Faster](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/patch-multiple-records-in-power-apps-10x-faster/)

I don't think you can apply this trick directly in your code (you must store the empty lines in a collection), but it could be something like that:

```
Patch('Printing Orders Details', PrintOrderDetailsGalleryCollection)
```

## Video:

As you are trying to make an **editable gallery**, you need to check this video form Reza Dorrani: [Power Apps Editable Grid using Gallery & Modern Controls (2023)](https://youtu.be/76RJyaoW0BQ). The same trick as Matthew is used: collect your empty items in a collection and do something like `Patch(SharePointSource, EditableItemsCollection)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my case the items inside the  gallery are not saved yet to sharepoint, so how i can loop through them?

Comment: When you said "i will add a new empty record inside the SharePoint list" I thought you have created empty items in SharePoint and that's why you wanted to update them. If not, you have to create, not update, the items. It's simpler. I will edit my answer.

Comment: yes i already created them as empty inside sharepoint,

Comment: i tired your code but it did not update the SharePoint list item,, also i can not access the datacard using ThisRecord

Comment: I don't understand why to talk about "update" SharePoint list if you want to "create" new items. It's very confusing. Maybe you have to edit your initial question. `Patch + Defaults` will create new item in the datasource for sure.

Comment: when you click on the + icon a new Print Order Details empty item will be created, i do not have any issue with this.. now you will get the new empty item inside the gallery,, and then you click on the submit button,,, now i am trying to Forall the gallery item values and update the realted items inside sharepoint

Comment: ,, also in your formula, you are trying to get the networkId using this formula `ThisRecord.PrintOrderNetworkComboBox.ID` .. but this record will list the item properties and not the gallery components ..

Comment: I still don't understand what are the "related items in SharePoint". If SharePoint items already exists, you have to update (Patch + Record), if not, you have to create new items (Patch + Defaults)

Comment: the related items in sharepoint, are the items inside the gallery that were created as empty items and need to be updated

Comment: Ok, so my initial answer was suitable. The items are created on SharePoint (with empty values), therefore they had an ID, so you can use a `LookUp` on these idenfiers.